# In Vim, can I conditionally turn off a plugin based on the environment?

Tags: vim, ack

My current Vim setup includes the [ack.vim plugin](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim). Now, I'd like to use the Vim setup I have on other systems, but some of those systems don't have ack installed. Is there a way for me to detect the presence or absence of ack in the .vimrc and turn the plugin on/off accordingly?

(Edit: fixed a typo.)

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way but this works:

```
call system('which ack')
if !v:shell_error
  " turn your plugin on
endif
```